# Does Blast have the same fighting abilities in the One Punch Man manga and in the webcomic?

Tags: one-punch-man

In chapter 166 of the *One-Punch Man* manga,

> Blast engages in a fight with Garou, and he shows his powers such as firing dimensional portals

Does he show any of this in the webcomic?